# jcarousel and Google Indexing

Tags: asp.net, jcarousel, google-index

I am using jcarousel to show item slides on my website.

FYI, I am passing in JSON string to add items to jcarousel.
But because jcarousel is being created using javascript and displayed at run-time -
the content is not indexed by Google.

To get the content indexed, I am thinking to remove jcarousel and add the content as normal.
And then use jQuery/javascript to scroll items.

Any other better ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems indeed the most relevant even if it increases the loading time of the page.

You can consult the official documentation on the subject of Google: [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)